# Make [azure-directory-b2c] a synonym of [azure-ad-b2c]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are currently 2 tags being used which references Microsoft's [Azure AD Business to Consumer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) product: [azure-directory-b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-directory-b2c) and [azure-ad-b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-b2c).

I would like to make [azure-ad-b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-b2c) the master tag, and have [azure-directory-b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-directory-b2c) be a synonym to that master tag.

Comment: Totally agree on that one. Semms legit.